# Android 2.2 - Visited Links Color

Tags: 2.2-froyo, browser

I just got the 2.2 update for my T-Mobile MyTouch 3G (3.5mm) and while playing around with the browser discovered that, unlike with the previous version, visited html links on web pages are now purple.  I understand the purpose this serves, but I personally HATE having visited links display with another color.

Anyone know of a setting that will disable this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in the settings for the default browser on my phone (Droid, Android 2.2.1). You're almost certainly going to need to try an alternative browser. I don't know if any of them offer that functionality either, though.